# MSAL Node / Electron - PublicClientApplication.acquireTokenByCode() accessing Tokens despite clearing accounts

Tags: node.js, electron, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to clear all access Tokens from Main.Ts in an Electron App without success.

On the Node side of the App, I have a `login` function that implements the Auth Code Flow with PKCE  - which works fine:

```
let login = async () => {
  try {
    const authResult = await getTokenInteractive(authCodeUrlParams);
    mainWindow.webContents.send(IpcMessages.XXX-XXXX, authResult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```
let getTokenInteractive = async (

tokenRequest: AuthorizationUrlRequest

): Promise\<AuthenticationResult\> =\> {

try {

     ...
     // Generate PKCE Challenge and Verifier before request
        const cryptoProvider = new CryptoProvider();
        const { challenge, verifier } = await cryptoProvider.generatePkceCodes();
    
     ...
     // Get Auth Code URL
    const authCodeUrl = await clientApplication.getAuthCodeUrl(
      localAuthCodeUrlParams
    );
    const authCode = await listenForAuthCode(authCodeUrl, authWindow);
    
    ...

// This works fine
const authResult: AuthenticationResult =
await clientApplication.acquireTokenByCode({
...authCodeRequest,
code: authCode,
codeVerifier: verifier,
});

    return authResult;

} catch (error) {

    throw error;

}
};
```

The `logout` function also clears the accounts:

```
    const logout = async () =\> {
         try {
   console.log("LOGOUT RECEIVED");
const accounts: AccountInfo\[\] = await clientApplication
.getTokenCache()
.getAllAccounts();
if (accounts && accounts.length \> 0) console.log(accounts);
await clientApplication.getTokenCache().removeAccount(accounts\[0\]);

     // Test to see if accounts are cleared returns '[]'
    const checkAccounts: AccountInfo[] = await clientApplication
      .getTokenCache()
      .getAllAccounts();
    
    console.log(checkAccounts);
    mainWindow.webContents.send(IpcMessages.USER_LOGGED_OUT);

} catch (err) {
console.log("Error in main.logout ", err);
}
};
```

Unfortunately, `acquireTokenByCode` still accesses the Token (?? How) when the user is redirected to a login page.

ps I've also checked local storage, Cookies etc in the browser and they are never populated (ie always remain empty).

I've seen numerous answers suggesting using a logout URL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/263335/msal-sign-out-does-not-appear-to-clear-cache.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/994601/logout-does-not-clear-session.html

However, these solutions down't work with Azure B2C. Also, redirecting using the `logout` endpoint using `Electron.shell(openExternal([url]))` also does nothing.

It's unbelievable that MS hasn't implemented a simple logout solution.

Question: Does anyone know how to stop tokens from being acquired WITHOUT having to open a native browser window or populate the Browser Window with a "Successfully signed out. You can now close this window" prompt ?

Thanks in advance.